# How is it possible to implement a realtime version of wc?

Tags: linux, bash, wc

I want a command(named **rtwc**) that acts like `wc -c`. it reads an input stream(stdin)
and writes the number of bytes read after 1 second then update the number every one second. In fact it shows the progress of reading.

This command is useful in a number of situations like performance testing

One can test the command with:

```
cat /dev/random | rtwc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Perhaps `watch` is the right way to tackle this?

Comment: Go ahead. What's stopping you?

Comment: This is just a set of requirements. What is your actual question? Someone who wanted to help you would have no idea what part of writing this program you're having trouble with.

Comment: Any hint to do it elegantly. also I wonder if there is an existing tool that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

On many Linux systems you can use `cpipe`, like in

```
cat /dev/urandom |cpipe -vr >/dev/null
```

You man need to install it.

Comment: Thanks, cpipe works and is interesting, but I want a solution that writes the output in one line and replaces the output every one second.